# Nativescript + Angular2 (2.0.0-beta.16) : "cannot read property 'extend' of undefined"

Tags: angular, nativescript

So it's been a while I've been using the 9th beta of Angular2 in my project so I decided to update to the latest version. But after I run the command "tns run android" or "tns livesync android", I have this message in the emulator :

[image: Error]

Here's my tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitOnError": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms"
    ]
}
```

and here's the [1st file](http://pastebin.com/pxVWZZw2) mentioned in the error message.
As you can see there are other files mentioned but like the 1st one, all these weren't made by myself. They were generated. So what can I do except getting back to 9th beta of Angular 2 ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried changing the target and module to different values. Such as "node" (for target).

Comment: It didn't change a thing :(